# HTML 5 and Javascript's Role?

Tags: javascript, html

Anyone clear on how big a role Javascript will play when HTML 5 comes around?  I'm deciding now whether to purchase a book on Javascript DOM or learn something useful like cooking with hemp oil.  I'm already weary of the past year and a half I've spent absorbing AS3.  I love it, I just don't want to be outmoded in 5 years when the iRevolutionaires rule the intergalactic space agency.

-Jascha

Comment: The use of JavaScript has just begun.

Comment: I marked this question 'subjective' as there's no definite answer to it. It's rather hard to look in the future, especially five years (let's see: no IE6 anymore, HTML 5 being rolled out more and more, more documents in G's cloud, etc.).

Comment: I guess the only definitive outcome will be if I buy the book or not :)

Comment: In that case, IMHO, you should really buy a good Javascript book to learn the language (there are several questions here about that). The only thing I strongly recommend is to first learn the language, before you dive into a framework like jQuery or Prototype. It's useful (and fun) to know what's going on 'under the hood' when using such a library. After all, you really want your car repair man to know how an engine works, before he just reads a computer display which guides him through the repair process.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

HTML is about content, and not behavior -- which means you'll still have, even with HTML 5, to know at least :

- HTML, for the content
- CSS, for the presentation
- And **Javascript for the behavior** *(dynamic stuff)*

So, **I don't think Javascript will be outmoded** in the next couple of years -- on the contrary, I would say, considering we are more and more going to use/develop web-applications.

Comment: Interesting.  I feel to some people, html 5 represents the end of flash.  Is that merely because of it's video support?

Comment: Maybe it's because HTML 5 also comes with a certain number of great functionnalities, like Drag and Drop, video *(as you said)*, offline-storage, ... Which means Flash will maybe not be needed for that anymore. But you'll still need some Javascript code to control those, of course.

Comment: @Jascha: I wouldn't look for the end of Flash anytime soon, no matter what Steve Jobs may think. Flash has the biggest penetration of any media plugin, has an enormous developer base, and is still more powerful and a better environment to work in (via Flex) than HTML5 and Javascript are. ActionScript (also based on EcmaScript) allows real class libraries, variable typing, non-prototype-based inheritance, etc., etc.

Comment: I understand you're being sarcastic, but I'm not sure what the target of that is. You can do drag'n'drop pretty easily in HTML 4, even, using Javascript. As I mentioned above, Flash offers some nice improvements over Javascript and even Javascript frameworks.

Comment: Please excuse the sarcasm. I love Actionscript 3.  My meaning was that there is so much more that you can do with Actionscript 3.  Complete RIAs with all the dragging and dropping you could possibly want.  I don't want it's usefulness to be under appreciated, so I made the winky face, hoping that would suffice, but I will defend it here more literally!

Comment: There will be no end of flash before all browsers will support any standardized video encoding in HTML5. I think the most flash content on web are flv players. (if I don't consider flash games ofcoarse)

Comment: Flash will end for browsers. Of course! :) Plugin? Crash? Install? New browser versions? Ubuntu issues? Anyone? :) And of course it will drop because AS3 IS indeed a proprietary language. No matter if it's been based on A B C bla bla. Abobe owns it. :) HTML5 as a long way to go to do the same things that AS3 does now but this does it with a need of a plugin (java applet times, again? No way!) :p But on web rules, I'm 100% with standards and with me are more 1000000 :) AS3 to rule? Sure. When it became a W3C recommendation. :) AS3 could be ok for IPads and stuff like that. Oh... no it can't. :)

Answer (score 4):

IMHO, Javascript will become even more important with HTML5. Knowing how to manipulate the DOM has always been important for interactive web apps, but now, in order to program a "canvas", to interact with the "clipboard", to manipulate an application "offline", to store/retrieve data from "localStorage", and to continue building Ajax-style interactivity, you'll need Javascript even more.

You'll also find that you can replace a lot of Flash/AS3 with HTML5/JS.

Don't write JS code where you don't have to though. Better animation, pseudo-class, and pseudo-element support in CSS lessens the amount of "styling" you'll need to write in JS.

Go buy a book (or two, or three).

Answer (score 2):

*If* HTML5 is a Flash killer than the following may suffice:

JavaScript === ActionScript && HTML5 === MXML

HTML5 is for content and layout, JavaScript is for interacting with the end-user. For instance, richer games are possible when using Canvas for display of graphics and JavaScript for interaction.

Comment: I think you meant Actionscript === JavaScript && HTML 5 === MXML?

Answer (score 2):

They are mentioning javascript in the lastest [working draft of the HTML5 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/). SVG, Canvas, et al... javascript is versatile with all of these.

But then again I'm told there is a lot of bio developments in Hemp from different consortiums. Though the consortiums are often ilegitimate, illegal, and/or not as public as the wc3. But, still, it gets more and more powerful, and unlikely to disappear.

On the basis that Javascript's versatility – with everything HTML5 and with being increasingly used beyond just the context of the browser – and Hemp being easier to pick up, I'd by the javascript book.

Answer (score 1):

HTML 5 will be about content, as HTML always has (or should have) been about.

JavaScript has always been about behaviour. If you want behaviour, learn JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Web pages are driven by four entities:

structure:  The structure of a document is given by its document tree. This is done by using well-formed HTML to determine elements.

appearance: The appearance of a document is determined by CSS.  CSS uses the structure of the document tree to determine the scope of sets of style rules.

behavior:  JavaScript causes behavior and interactivity to be executed on the client side.

server-side activity:  PHP and its relatives run on a server and format a web page, which is then processed by the client.

It seems to me that JavaScript and its libraries will be here for a long time. It is one of the pillars of the web.