# HTML5 and JavaScript, how they're related?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to move from HTML 4.01 to HTML5.Does that mean I've to learn JavaScript first, then move to learn advance topics on HTML5 like canvas , local storage,....?

Comment: Not really a programming question. Better posted on http://programmers.stackexchange.com.

Comment: You don't need any Javascript to use the `<section>` tag

Comment: I'm not talking about the basics of HTML5, I'm talking about more advance HTML5 topics, like canvas.

Comment: So you're asking whether you need to know Javascript in order to use HTML5 Javascript features?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript is basically the programming language for dynamic behavior in HTML 5. You would model your look and feel using HTML and CSS, and model the behavior using JavaScript. Refer to [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2388578/html-5-and-javascripts-role) that discusses this topic in more depth.

And yes, if you are serious about HTML 5 you probably want to be familiar ***at least*** on a cursory level with Javascript.

Comment: Note that JavaScript is also the programming language for dynamic behavior in HTML 4 :-)

Comment: @Pointy - Yes! But HTML4 is so boring, its not even Turing complete.

Answer (score 0):

Just knowing Html 4 or 5, without CSS and javascript is of no use. You should know CSS to style your elements and define the layout in which your page should appear to the user and using javascript(client-side script) you can create an interactive apps, which helps you to respond to the user behavior dynamically.

Simply,

**HTML** defines **Structure**

**CSS** defines **Presentation**

**Javascript** defines **Behaviour**